# PHP array error in displaying a table

Tags: php, html, mysql, arrays, html-table

I am trying to display all the data from a mysql table into a html table and the PHP is getting the data fine but the table isn't displaying it properly this is my code:

```
<table border="1">
<tr>
<td>ID</td>
<td>Name</td>
<td>Phone Number</td>
<td>Email</td>
<td>Time</td>
<td>Number Of People</td>
<td>Time Placed</td>
</tr>
<?php

$host = "localhost";
$database = "reservation";
$user = "root";
$pass = "root";

//connection to the database
mysql_connect($host, $user, $pass)
or die ('cannot connect to the database: ' . mysql_error());

//select the database
mysql_select_db($database)
or die ('cannot select database: ' . mysql_error());

$sql = "SELECT * FROM reservation ORDER BY timeplaced";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
while($data = mysql_fetch_row($result)){

  echo("<tr><td>$data[0]</td><td>$data[1]</td><td>$data[2]</td></tr><td>$data[3]</td></tr><td>$data[4]</td></tr><td>$data[5]</td></tr><td>$data[6]</td></tr>");

}



?>
</table>
```

Please help.

Comment: please use fetch_assoc.if anybody change order of mysql column, it will cause error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM reservation ORDER BY timeplaced";
 $result = mysql_query($sql);
 while($data = mysql_fetch_row($result)){

 echo("<tr>
    <td>$data[0]</td>
    <td>$data[1]</td>
    <td>$data[2]</td>
    <td>$data[3]</td>
    <td>$data[4]</td>
    <td>$data[5]</td>
    <td>$data[6]</td>
</tr>");

 }
```

when you use TDs in TR, they all must be same numbers, or use colspan, try the above echo statement, it will display your table properly.

Comment: no there are mistakes tr and td, see carefully, did u see that `<td>$data[2]</td></tr><td>$data[3]</td>`

Comment: Nomi is right. I was wondering myself why everyone was pasting all those `tr`s.

Answer (score 1):

When you are echoing array items it should be

```
echo "<tr><td>" . $data[0] . "</td></tr>";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "<tr><td>{$data[0]}</td><td>{$data[1]}</td><td>{$data[2]}</td></tr><td>{$data[3]}</td></tr><td>{$data[4]}</td></tr><td>{$data[5]}</td></tr><td>{$data[6]}</td></tr>";
```

Use braces.